# What is happens with the server load average too high

Tags: overloading

i have a problem with my server.checked connecting netstat -nat |wc -l show 1150. Now load average: 502.61, 500.38, 507.66

I have to reboot it frequently, if not reboot it can be up to load average: 700
Tasks: 465 total, 150 running, 363 sleeping, 5 stopped, 0 zombie
Cpu(s): 24.1%us, 75.6%sy, 0.0%ni, 0.0%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.2%si, 0.0%st

alway running up and not down. I have stopped all service but it still high load.
nginx, apache, mysql, named, .. stop
It is why someone can help me? Thank you very much

Comment: This is a server issue, not a programming issue.  Try asking on serverfault.com instead.  Also good luck, as these are difficult programs to track.